# Django - Using a Form or ModelForms to update multiple tables?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a one form that when submitted will either create or update a record based on validation of the PK that was submitted. This form will need to interact with at least two models though. So my question would be, Would it be better to create one form and handle the DB interaction in the view or somehow create a ModelForm that will update both tables when submitted? 
I understand that a modelform can only have one model attached to it.

Ex. I have a model called "Item" with fields "name" PK, "description" and "price".
Another model called "Requisition" with fields "ID" PK, "item" FK to Item, "signature"

How should i go about creating a form that when submitted will take the fields at face value and create a record for the requisition table but also create or update the item table based on the value entered?

If i create a modelform on Requisition the FK field displays a dropdown which is not what I want. I want it to be a textfield.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Typically a `ModelForm` is "bound" to a single model, so you will need to implement some extra logic in a "vanilla" `Form`.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance as I am fairly new to django. What is a "vanilla" form? Is that was you would just call a normal form?

Comment: [vanilla](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=vanilla+definition&oq=vanilla+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l4.2828j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8): having no special or extra features; ordinary or standard.